# Is it ok to "reuse" or plagiarize comments when reviewing first questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-page

I've seen this comment by [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) on non-answers and rants:

> Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the
>   question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a
>   comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you
>   have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
>   button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

and I thought it was great and copied it to some first posts I was reviewing –I even added markdown links for them to work when pasted to the comment box.

Is that ok? Should I credit [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)? Are there canned responses available to higher rep users that are not available to me (~750)?

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange Review Comments](https://georgegarside.com/blog/stack-exchange-review-comments/)

Comment: Thanks @grgarside, I've already added the extension, I'll add your JSON (when I learn where).

Comment: I need to update that page in the near future FWIW; I've changed the wording of a few of those and added a few new ones.

Comment: Actually, I can't find out how to add / remove comments from the list, is there some kind of manual?

Comment: I just gathered all the canned responses as I saw them & copy/pasted to a local file, which I keep open as I'm going through review queues. That particular one, I'm sure I got from @grgarside in the first place anyway, with the added 'welcome' for new users.

Comment: Even as a 10k user you don't always get the option to send a canned response - Late Answers, for instance don't have a 'vote to close' but must be flagged for non-answers, so that's when the copy/paste comes in handy - an example [though I'm not sure if you'll be able to see it] http://apple.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/117083

Comment: @Tetsujin do you think you could share your list in chat? Or link to a GitHub gist here?

Comment: It was George's list really, tweaked from the canned responses, though his page seems to have vanished. Let me flag him to this comment & see if there's potential for its reappearance - @grgarside

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always ask the author in [chat] or officially here on meta like you did. I can't see anyone getting too worked up if you are using a comment for kind, critical feedback to a poster.

The text you selected is a canned response in the [/review queue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review) that you'll earn once you reach that [reputation milestone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Is that the 10k milestone? I have access to review but not these canned responses.